# C Preprocessor, strip parens from string

Tags: c-preprocessor

I'm working with some C preprocessor macros that, thanks to changes elsewhere, are now showing up like (("Foo")) instead of "Foo".  The problem is, elsewhere in the code, this is breaking concatenations.

E.G.

```
#include "some_external_FOO_and_FILE_PATH_declarations.h" 
//FOO is (("Foo"))
const char* filepath = FILE_PATH(FOO "/bar")
//throws error
```

How can I get FOO to look like "Foo" again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
#define UNPAREN(...) #__VA_ARGS__
const char *filepath = FILEPATH(UNPAREN(FOO) "bar")
```

Comment: UPDATE: let's say:
#define FOO ("bar")
Then this will produce something like: "FOO".  That's probably not what you want.
#define UNPAREN(...) __VA_ARGS__
(note lack of #) will produce "bar", but there's a trick.  You have to call it like:
UNPAREN FOO
instead of
UNPAREN(FOO)
because the parens are already there, get it?  

Note this doesn't work very well for nested parens...